# How to console log in terminal and write in file at the same time with Pino and Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pinojs

I have this simple function that I created to log whatever happens in my code:

```js
const pino = require('pino')

module.exports = pino({
  transport: {
    target: "pino-pretty",
    options: {
      translateTime: "SYS:dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:ss",
      ignore: "pid,hostname",
      destination: './logs/logs.txt'
    }
  }
})
```

The problem with `destination`. If this option is, `pino` will write everything in file, not in console, if there is not, will print in console, but not in file. I want to print in console and write logs at the same time.

Is this possible?

Comment: see if this helps https://github.com/pinojs/pino/issues/1341

Answer (score 7):

I know this is old, but I thought I'd drop this in as I'm working with it right now.

```
transport: {
    targets: [
        {
            level: 'info',
            target: 'pino-pretty',
            options: {}
        },
        {
            level: 'trace',
            target: 'pino/file',
            options: { destination: './pino-logger.log' }
        }
    ],
},
```

You can set up multiple targets and distinguish which will receive what levels and options. Hope that helps anyone still looking around.